# Offset line, when zooming out line extends at intersections

Tags: arcmap, symbology, offset

[[image: Offset_ZoomingIn][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBcij.jpg)[[image: Offset_ZoomingOut]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR9eT.png)I'm doing offset in ArcGIS in a cartographic line symbol. Before the offset the line in all scales appears OK. But when zooming out, the offset line extends out at intersections. While when zooming in, the offset line appears OK.

Could some one help me on that issue?

Comment: Can you include a picture to illustrate what you are trying to describe in words, please?

Comment: I have just added two pics. First one with zooming in after the Offset of line. And second one with zooming out after the Offset.